# Google Sheets script - getLastRow error "The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some Google script iterating through sheets in a Google Sheets spreadsheet. I'm copying data from several sheets to one specific one. For one particular sheet calls to getLastRow or getLastColumn throw the error, "The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet". So even this errors:

```
for (var i = 0; i < clickData.length; i++) {
  Logger.log(clickData[i].getLastRow());
}
```

The sheet in question has a few hundred rows of data, plus a bunch of empty rows after that. There are 16 items in the clickData array, the error is when i is 7.

Comment: Hello @toby1kenobi, what does the `clickData` array represent? Is it an array of sheets?  Moreover, have you tried calling `getLastRow()-1`? Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! Yes exactly, it's an array of sheets. Just calling getLastRow() causes that error (so calling it and trying to subtract 1 from the result also throws the error)

Comment: Hello @toby1kenobi, do you have a sanitized copy of the sheet in question that you wouldn't mind sharing? Cheers!

Comment: The error is somewhere else. Your code is irrelevant to the error. Try debugging anywhere with `.getRange` calls

Comment: @TheMaster This helped - if I comment out a line with getRange in that's four lines after the one with the error, the error disappears. Weird but gives me something else to look at - thanks!

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code you have used in this situation? @toby1kenobi

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here? I'm dealing with the same problem.